# Liferay - shutdown

Tags: liferay, shutdown

I am using liferay 6.1.0 GA1.

In my project, I am using two nodes for my portal.

When I'm using default liferay shutdown option, it's restarting one, which I suppose is good behaviour. Is there any way I can synergize/merge this liferay shutdown option to work on both nodes?

Edit: Additional question. Where I can change default behaviour of shutdown?

Comment: What is the server you are using? I think you will have to write a custom script for that.

Comment: I am using tomcat 7.0.37. Could You be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

I have not done something like this. But [here](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/administration/-/ai/advanced-liferay-configurati-4) in docs i gives some ideas.

```
global.shutdown.events=com.liferay.portal.events.GlobalShutdownAction
```

When you define this action in portal-ext.properties and implement it, it will run when the portal shuts down. In this action you can call a custom script to stop the other instances also.